# How to shorten this J code? (Or write shorter code in another language)

Tags: code-golf, tips

I decided to learn J so that I could better take part in code golfing. Starting it off relatively simple, I tried writing a solution to this problem:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

After a bit of tinkering, I came up with the following J code that solves it:

```
x=:i.1000
+/x#(0=3|x)+.0=5|x
```

Basically, what I'm doing is taking two lists of numbers from 1 to 1000, and finding one modulo 3, and the other modulo 5. Then I OR them together to get a list of indicies where a number is divisible by either 3 or 5. I then use that to sum the numbers.

What I ask is, how do I shorten this? I'm new to J and so do not have enough experience to shorten it any further.

Also, if anyone has a solution shorter than this in another language, I'd be interested to see that as well!

Comment: [Project Euler problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)

Comment: 6 bytes: `233168`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Employing a few [forks](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/primer/fork.htm), a [hook](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/primer/hook.htm) and the fact that J works well on lists:

```
+/(#~[:+./0=3 5|/])i.1000
```

This answer uses your algorithm, but just uses some J tricks to make it a bit shorter. I'm fairly sure that this can be made shorter still, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's a slightly different way of doing it that results in an even shorter solution.

Here's a list of some things I've done here.

First, I've combined the `3|x` and the `5|x` into one operation `3 5|/x`. This uses the table adverb `/` to do both operations at once:

```
   3 5|/i.20
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4
```

Next, I've combined the `|/`, the `0=`, the `+.`, and the `#` into a train of verbs using forks and a hook. The verb train breaks down into groups of three:

```
3 5|/]
```

this is the same as the above, except I'm using `]` to grab the list to the right of the brackets.

```
0=x
```

`x` is the result of the previous fork which is fed into the next.

```
[:+./x
```

as before the result so far gets fed into this fork. `[:` tells the verb `+./` that it should use its monadic (one argument) form. The `/` inserts the +. between the top and bottom rows of the result so far.

```
#~x
```

This is the hook. The result so far is fed in as the right argument, but the left argument is the value outside the brackets (`i.1000`) again. So this is equivalent to `(i.1000)#~x`. The `~` just reverses the order of the arguments.

Then at the end I just use the `+/` as you did.

Comment: Is there anyway you could add a small explanation to what/how you're doing it?

Comment: Yep, just working on that now. :-)

Comment: `+/(#~0=[:*/3 5|/])i.1e3` is two chars shorter. Basically changing OR with multiplication and shortening the number 1000.

Answer (score 4):

Using a slightly different method than my other answer:

```
+/+/((]*[>])3 5*/i.)1000
```

Here, I'm multiplying 3 and 5 by all the numbers up to 1000, throwing away anything that's not less than 1000 and then summing them. It's a shame about the ugly `+/+/` at the end.

Here we have a fork:

```
3 5*/i.
```

followed by a hook:

```
(]*[>])x
```

**EDIT:**

As [randomra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7311/randomra) points out, I forgot about duplicates. This should fix that:

```
+/~.,((]*>)3 5*/i.)1000
```

I've also realised that `[>]` is the same as `>` (not the first time I've had that redundancy in my answer)

Comment: You double count numbers divisible by 15.

Comment: Ooh, never considered that.

Comment: your first "+/" just removes shape - can use monadic `;` instead
double count can be fixed with "nub" `~.`
your approach is good and leads to **22 bytes** `+/~.;((]*>)3 5*/i.)1e3`

Comment: @jayprich my shortest version is 23 bytes at the end of the answer. It's pretty much what you've got without the `1e3` for the `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of swerves on the above to shave some bytes off

correct result `233168`

- 25 bytes `+/x#(0=3|x)+.0=5|x=:i.1e3`
- 24 bytes `+/(#~[:+./0=3 5|/])i.1e3`
- 22 bytes `+/~.;((]*>)3 5*/i.)1e3`

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), testing HCF 21 bytes

```
+/(*1&<@(15&+.))i.1e3
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##bcuxCsIwFIXhPU9xsEvS4E2bWJFKHBScxMFVOgatFJFaIUPpq8cU2kHwwNn@7xHOewKk8gnPrOm9kJTZove2rCl3Bmjc89bdoQugde9P00Ebk683bII8Ga6lJBU1il5VYnLz9GouB9pyXqU7EcNU1SR@ulhqxpx/tbAlMoxfEg6X0zH8t0GEBWEUXw)